# What to do about old unanswered questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicates, best-practices, unanswered-questions

I am relatively new to SE and I am wondering what is the best thing to do when I ask a question that remains unanswered (not even through comments) for a long time? Is it allowed to re-ask the same question after enough time has passed?

P.s. I am excluding bounties as they seem costly for me right now

Comment: As the linked answer says:  bounties are the way to do this, and they are costly intentionally. To earn reputation for bounties, find other ways to engage with our community.